# What are my network and computer IP addresses?

Tags: networking, scanner, sane, xsane

I'm trying to configure my locally-connected (USB) HP Deskjet F380 All-in-One to work with SANE and some PDF software (as per the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane.d%20tutorial )... But I need to know my network IP address and my machine (computer) IP address.

How do I identify this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try `ifconfig`. If you are directly connected to internet or not behind a router, then It will show your public and local IPs, both.

find the lines **`inet addr:X.X.X.X`**. Here `X.X.X.X` will be your ip. (It might be local/private ip like 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.X.X or public ip like 117.197.X.X)

If you are behind a router, then your computer will not know about the public IP address as the router does a network address translation. You could request this website using `wget` to know public IP, `wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo`

OR Simply go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and search `my ip`.

Comment: I'm quite sure he meant his local IP.

Comment: OK. Edited the reply, It should be fine!! Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the network icon in the top left of your screen:

[image]

And then select Connection Information, you will see a window with all the information you need:

[image]

Comment: I get pretty much the same thing as you (just with different IP addresses) - the IP address under "IPv4" is my network right? But what's the IP address of my actual computer?

Comment: @GregoryOpera the part that says "IP Address" is your local system IP.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the GUI method or you have non-Unity/Gnome desktop, the easiest and infallible way is:

```
➜  ~  sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for braiam: 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:d4:13:1c:0f  
          inet addr:X.X.X.X  Bcast:0.0.0.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::213:d4fb:fe13:1f0f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:207094 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:134920 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:280125899 (267.1 MiB)  TX bytes:11303141 (10.7 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4972 (4.8 KiB)  TX bytes:4972 (4.8 KiB)
```

The important part is where it says `inet addr`. That's your system IP.